# month end date and month start date for given date in Hive SQL

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hiveql

For given any date in between in month, I need to get month_end_date and month_start_date in hive SQL

**Month_start_date:** is working fine as shown below img..

```
date_format(date_sub(DATA_DATE, (int(SUBSTR(expl.Time_Dim, 2,length(expl.Time_Dim))) - 1) * 7 ) , 'yyyy-MM-01') AS month_start_date
```

**month_end_date:** is giving sequence of numbers inbetween 32 and 9 for given code..

```
date_format(date_sub(DATA_DATE, (int(SUBSTR(expl.Time_Dim, 2,length(expl.Time_Dim))) - 1)),'yyyy-MM-DD') AS month_end_date,
```

[image]

Comment: `last_day(string date)`. First day can be calculated easier too - `date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM-01')`.

Comment: Hi Ben refeed to that hive link only. From that reference i formed month_start_date. But 
 with Month_end_date i am facing problem.  Need to take date values from ----`(expl.Time_Dim, 2,length(expl.Time_Dim))`----- to get month_end_date

Comment: Please can you update the question to show what `expl.Time_Dim` is? Also if you can calculate `month_start_date` correctly then you can just run `last_day(month_start_date)`.

Comment: yeah last_day(month_start_date) worked restructured the whole query for this ... Thanks Ben :)